# How to align uneven child Linear Layouts?

Tags: android, xml

I have 2 child vertical Linear Layouts in a parent horizontal LinearLayout (i.e. 2 columns). The column on the left has only 5 items with fixed height (number blocks), while the column on the right has a lot more items with variable height (5 question blocks and 5 answer blocks).

I want to align each number block with a question block using XML only. Please see code and screenshot below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/map"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.karim.capitalquiz.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="1)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="2)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="3)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="4)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="5)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What's the capital of Egypt?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Athens"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Cairo"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Luxor"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What province is the capital of Canada in, and what's the capital of that province?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Alberta"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calgry"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Toronto"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Ontario"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What's the capital of Germany?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Frankfurt"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Berlin"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Halifax"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What's the capital of China?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Tokyo"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Bejing"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hong Kong"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What's the capital of Poland?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:hint="Capital of Poland?"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D9FFECB3"
        android:text="Submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[Screenshot of what this XML code currently looks like. I need those margin gaps to line up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdq1A.png)

Comment: keep that number 1,2,3,4,5 also inside the same layout eg: in your parent you can have 5 vertical layouts,, go to a a child layout and add question number and question again as children. 
or make the question number relative an position it

Comment: is it solved???

Answer (score 1):

This is too much work for something simple. Don't make your items static, try to make them dynamic.

I would recommend creating a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, preparing data dynamically and adding each question as a list item.

Your list item would be probably a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` that has question number on the left and question on the right.

This image is just a sample. Your item view would be more complicated.

It also helps you in the future to modify/extend the list easily.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#99FFECB3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="1)"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What's the capital of Egypt?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Athens"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Cairo"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Luxor"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#99FFECB3"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="2)"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What province is the capital of Canada in, and what's the capital of that province?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Alberta"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calgry"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Toronto"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Ontario"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#99FFECB3"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="3)"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What's the capital of Germany?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Frankfurt"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Berlin"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Halifax"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#99FFECB3"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="4)"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What's the capital of China?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Tokyo"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Bejing"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hong Kong"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#99FFECB3"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="5)"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What's the capital of Poland?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:hint="Capital of Poland?"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#D9FFECB3"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

[image]

Comment: I have separated child with each question so that it will be center aligned  to each question

Comment: I have seprated each child view with respected question hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your adapter, inside the getView() method, you can use the position to set the index number. in your listitem textView to show the number, use it in getView() method

textview will show your position number;

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  View row = convertView;
  ViewHolder mHolder = new ViewHolder();

  if (row == null) {

   // rest of your code
   mHolder.mseqNotxt = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_view);    

    row.setTag(mHolder);

  } else {
    // recycling of cells
    mHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
  }

  //rest of your code

  mHolder.mseqNotxt.setText("" + position);

  return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/map"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.karim.capitalquiz.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="1)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/q1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="#99FFECB3"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:text="What's the capital of Egypt?"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#99FFECB3"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:paddingRight="8dp"
                            android:text="Athens"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:paddingRight="8dp"
                            android:text="Cairo"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Luxor"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </RadioGroup>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="2)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/q2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="What province is the capital of Canada in, and what's the capital of that province?"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="3)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Alberta"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calgry"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Toronto"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Ontario"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="4)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/q3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#99FFECB3"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:text="What's the capital of Germany?"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#99FFECB3"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:paddingRight="8dp"
                            android:text="Frankfurt"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:paddingRight="8dp"
                            android:text="Berlin"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Halifax"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </RadioGroup>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#99FFECB3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="5)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/q4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#99FFECB3"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:text="What's the capital of China?"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioGroup4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#99FFECB3"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:paddingRight="8dp"
                            android:text="Tokyo"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:paddingRight="8dp"
                            android:text="Bejing"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Hong Kong"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D9FFECB3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```